# Storybook not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

Here's my component:

`Alert.tsx`

```
import { Alert } from "react-bootstrap";

export enum AlertVariants {
  success = "success",
  danger = "danger",
}

export interface IAlertComponent {
  handleClose(): void;
  header: string;
  children: string;
  variant: AlertVariants;
}
export const AlertComponent = ({
  handleClose,
  header,
  children,
  variant,
}: IAlertComponent) => {
  return (
    <Alert variant={variant} onClose={handleClose} dismissible>
      <Alert.Heading>{header}</Alert.Heading>
      <p>{children}</p>
    </Alert>
  );
};
```

Here's the story:

`Alert.stories.tsx`

```
import { Meta, Story } from "@storybook/react";
import {
  AlertComponent,
  IAlertComponent,
  AlertVariants,
} from "../components/Alert";

const Template: Story<IAlertComponent> = (args) => <AlertComponent {...args} />;

export default {
  title: "Alert",
  component: AlertComponent,
} as Meta;

export const Alert = () => Template.bind({});
Alert.args = {
  handleClose: () => console.log("close"),
  header: "header",
  children: "content",
  variant: AlertVariants.danger,
};

export const tmp = () => <div>test</div>; // this gets rendered
```

And after I run `yarn storybook`, I see this:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Edit:

If I do this in `Alert.stories.tsx`, it renders. So it must be smth with the args

```
export const tmp = () => (
  <AlertComponent
    handleClose={() => {}}
    header={"hedaer"}
    variant={AlertVariants.danger}
  >
    test
  </AlertComponent>
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must be tired. I was doing

```
export const Alert = () => Template.bind({});
```

instead of

```
export const Alert = Template.bind({});
```